# How to create a script which opens the browser and logins to a particular Gmail account?

Tags: command-line, bash, gmail

I have created a bash script `login.sh`. I want it to open the browser and login to my Gmail account.

I tried using the following command to open the browser with www.gmail.com.

```
xdg-open http://gmail.com
```

It opens Gmail home page perfectly.

But I don't know how to pass the `username` and `password` for login to Gmail from the  bash script.

Is it possible to open the browser and login to Gmail from a script?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail does not allow logging in from the url(or basic HTTP auth in general), my best guess would be to use something like the selenium webdriver to script the form filling as well as clicking the login button.

Comment: I already think about that, I just want to know without using selenium webdriver is it possible or not.    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can script the mouse movements, clicks and keyboard. More detailed information [here](http://tuxradar.com/content/xdotool-script-your-mouse). There is also a demonstration [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WycNY44n6e4) and you can find plenty of more online.

A minimal example to get the idea is:

```
xdotool mousemove 999 999; sleep .1 # coordinates of username field
xdotool click 1; sleep .1
xdotool type; sleep .1 # type your username, and then repeat for the password and login button
```

I used sleep in case it is too fast for the browser/computer; you can remove it or augment its values.
Finally, you can get your mouse's coordinates with

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

Comment: can you please elaborate it with example, so i can easily understood it